# Jade удаление комментариев

Tags: html, компиляция, jade, комментарии

Здравствуйте, как в html Jade удалять комментарии на выходе?

Answer (score 1):

Jade переименован в Pug. Список изменений можете посмотреть [здесь](https://pugjs.org/api/migration-v2.html). Скорее всего эти изменений вас не коснуться и вы можете использовать pug так же как jade.

Чтобы комментарии из pug/jade не попадали в скомпилированный html их нужно писать через два слеша и тире

```
//- комментарий
div
div
```

Ссылка на документацию: [Comments - Pug](https://pugjs.org/language/comments.html)

Comment: а у меня именно  jade работает , jade index.jade - работает

Comment: @Geyan Although .jade is still supported, it is deprecated, and all users are encouraged to transition to .pug immediately. [Project Rename](https://pugjs.org/api/migration-v2.html#project-rename)

Comment: Но работает хоть и deprecsted